# Mysql insert while selecting

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table with words: ID; NAME

```
1-dog
2-log
3-for
```

Then I have a table with characters: ID; NAME

```
1-_og
2-_or
3-_ot
```

Now I have a thirth relational table (lets call it words_and_characters) where I want to put ids from table words and id from table characters that "match".
The table id composed by ID, WORD_ID, CHARACTER_ID

In the example above, the table words_and_characters should contain the following:

```
1-1-1 (the match is "dog" and "_og")
2-2-1 (the match is "log" and "_og")
3-3-2 (the match is "for" and "_or")
```

I begun writing a stored procedure with a first cursor for iteratin through the table characters according to this:

```
select id, name from characters;
```

And putting the date this way:

```
FETCH curs1 INTO i,n;
```

Now, in each iteration, I wanted to do something like:

```
select * from words where name like n;
```

Well, Im afraid this is a little bit ineffective, especially if there is a lot of data.
Is there a better way to do this you think? Maybe I could also avoid writing a stored procedure and just have some kind of advances sql insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JOIN:

```
INSERT INTO words_and_characters (word_id, character_id)
SELECT w.id, c.id
FROM words AS w
JOIN characters AS c ON w.name LIKE c.name
```